# React zoom and scroll on img edges

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Trying next code I reached almost right functionality BUT it's seems like it doesn't rerender and doesn't update current picture in state. What is interesting scrolling logic works right, and buttons also.

```
import { TransformWrapper, TransformComponent } from "react-zoom-pan-pinch";


const ModalCarousel = ({ handleModalClose, 
data, //current picture in array of pictures
next, // set next picture in pictures state
previous // set previous picture in pictures state
}) => {
  let touchStart = useRef(null);
  let touchEnd = useRef(null);

  const minSwipeDistance = 100;

  const onTouchStart = (e) => {
    touchEnd = null; 
    touchStart = e.clientX;
  };

  const onTouchMove = (e) => (touchEnd = e.clientX);

  const onTouchEnd = () => {
    if (!touchStart || !touchEnd) return;
    const distance = touchStart - touchEnd;
    const isLeftSwipe = distance > minSwipeDistance;
    const isRightSwipe = distance < -minSwipeDistance;
    if (isLeftSwipe || isRightSwipe) isLeftSwipe ? previous() : next();
  };

         return(
      <div className={styles.picture} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
        {isMobile ? null : (
          <div className={styles.previous}>
            <button onClick={next}>{""}</button>
          </div>
        )}
            <TransformWrapper
            disablePadding={true}
            onPanning={({ state, instance }, event) => {
              if (state.scale === 1) onTouchMove(event);
              if (
                Math.ceil(state.positionX) ===
                  Math.ceil(instance.bounds.maxPositionX) ||
                (Math.ceil(state.positionX) ===
                  Math.ceil(instance.bounds.minPositionX) &&
                  state.scale >= 1.4)
              ) {
                onTouchMove(event);
              }
            }}
            onPanningStart={(_, event) => {
              onTouchStart(event);
            }}
            onPanningStop={onTouchEnd}
          >
            <TransformComponent>
              <ModalImage
                key={data[0].id}
                src={baseUrl + data[0].attributes.url}
              />
            </TransformComponent>
          </TransformWrapper>
        {isMobile ? null : (
          <div className={styles.next}>
            <button onClick={previous}>{""}</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
          )
}
```

So I hope that somebody have an idea (or experience using this lib) how can I solve that.
Good example of what I expect is an iPhone's standard gallery.
If you know another way to create same functionality also please be my guest, for me to use this library is not so important.

**Solved**. That was pretty easy. I understood that if my buttons works and cause rerender of all component, so I can use refs of buttons inside my swipeHandlers and call onClick functions (buttonRef.current.click();) what gives me exactly the same result what I wanted.